# Websocket RFC6455 connections - How is this handled server side?

Tags: html, websocket

I am would like to create a websocket server. I understand that the client will make a request and that a partially encrypted response needs to be sent back to the client. My question is does that connection need to stay open to handle the websocket messages after the connection is made. Or does the client establish a new connection after receiving the response from the server?

Thanks,

-ren

Comment: What language do you plan to create your server using?  There are open source servers available for several different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [an article](http://bohuco.net/blog/2010/07/php-websocket-server-the-handshake/) on the websockets handshake.

And, a [sample implementation](http://bohuco.net/dev/websocket/?source=WebSocketServer.php) of a websockets server in PHP.

The socket stays open.

The whole protocol is described in [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

Comment: The sample implementation is of hixie-76 and not the current RFC 6455 version.